# Is it possible to bind a gridview column onto a seperate datasource?

Tags: asp.net

First, start with two objects.

```
Object
{
    int id {get; set;}
    string description {get; set;}
}

ObjectName
{
    int id {get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
}
```

Let's say I have your average gridview:

```
List<Object> = GetListOfObjects();
MyGridview.DataSource = List<Object>;
```

But I want one of the columns to come from the list of names, where the ids are the same.

Psuedocode:

```
the ID column from MyGridview = List<ObjectNames>.Where(x=> x.id = myGridview.Id);
```

So basically, replacing the column of IDs with the column of names with those ids.
Is that possible to do? How would I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the data one datasource.  You can create an anonymous type that will hold data from both collections.

```
var combined = from x in myobjects
               join y in myobjectnames on x.id equals y.id
               select new {
                  Id = x.Id,
                  Name = y.Name,
                  // any other data you need  
               }
```